# Nginx Rverse Proxy to Tomcat (simple yes….? NO)

Tags: docker, tomcat, nginx

I have created a docker-compose file to spin up both an nginx and tomcat image. I use volumised files such /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
Same for Tomcat but with xml config files and webapps.

Both spin up and run fine… on their own. I can browse to Nginx and get the welcom page and the same for Tomcat on their respective ports, 81/8080.

However I cannot proxy the request to the backend tomcat. I’ll admit, I’m Apache and have been for years but I need to experiment.

My nginx.conf hasnt changed, its still default. I have an app.conf for the tomcat application (below). I do try and CMD mv the default.conf in teh tomcat Dockerfile but it still remains along side my app.conf so that maybe causing the issue?
my app.conf config is here: (apologies, couldnt get the code to output properly)

```
"server {
 listen *:81;

set  $allowOriginSite *;
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  combined;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

# Upload size unlimited
client_max_body_size 0;

location /evf {
    proxy_pass http://tomcat:8080;

    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_set_header Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
}
}
```

tomcat:8080 being the name of the service in my docker-compose file.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you,
Craig

docker-compose.yml for reference;
    version: '3'

```
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: nginx:evf
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    networks:
      - evf
    container_name: evf-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/config/nginx-evf.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-evf.conf
      - ./volumes/config/default.conf.disabled:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.disabled
    ports:
      - "81:80"
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat
    working_dir: /usr/local/tomcat
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/config/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
      - ./volumes/webapps/EVF.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/EVF.war
    networks:
      - evf
    container_name: evf-tomcat
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" #expose 8080 externally to test connectivity.

networks:
  evf:
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post the `docker-compose.yml`? Kind of sounds that you havent linked the tomcat and nginx containers or created a network for them.

Comment: Sure, here it is... above

Comment: So you are not defining whether the `evf` network is external or not at all?

Comment: Hmm, I would have assumed it be internal. I thought when I hit the proxy, the proxy is aware of the internal network evf and pass on accordingly?

Comment: just add `external: false` after the `evf` part. Im not even sure if what you have there is legal yml

Comment: Hi tried that to no avail.  The config is sound, its pretty similar to our alfresco setup.  The networks are defined exactly the same.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx conf you have `listen *:81` but you are exposing port `80` with `"81:80"`.

So eiter expose port `81` with `"81:81"` or change you nginx config to `listen *:80`.

If the second option does not work try to replace the original nginx config by changing the volume file in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  - ./nginx/nginx-evf.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: Apologies, had an unexpcted week off.  You'r right, I had the ports the wrong way round.  However, it still doesnt work and now get a 502 Gateway error.  Nginx is reporting " connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,"

Comment: Is your Tomcat running?

Comment: Yes, tomcat is running.  I have made progress but stil getting errors as I move forward.  I'm gong to leave this post as its not achieving much.  Will start a new post if needed.